# Auto increment after concatenating 3 strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Problem:  I need a formula to automatically increment when dragging down.  Since the 3 strings are joined by concatenating, it doesn't seem to work.

```
=CONCATENATE("Sheet2!", SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("String to Search For", Sheet2!$13:$13,0),4),1,""),"17")
```

String 1 is a separate sheet reference (Sheet2!)

String 2 is the column number converted to column letter where string to be searched is found using `MATCH`, `ADDRESS`, and `SUBSTITUTE`.  In this case it was column 2 converted to B.

String 3 is the row number that I need information from IF string searched is found

After concatenating these, I need to drag it down 5000 rows and increment String 3 (the row number) but because the reference is concatenated, it will not increment.  I've tried everything!  Please help!

Comment: Put String 3 in a separate column, CONCATENATE it with the other two, drag to extend both columns together to 5000 rows. Not work?

Comment: Does your formula start in row 2?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot.  I have conditionals based on the concatenation of all 3 strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `ROWS` function, e.g. if you put the first formula in **Z2** use this version copied down

`=CONCATENATE("Sheet2!", SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("String to Search For", Sheet2!$13:$13,0),4),1,""),"17"+ROWS(Z$2:Z2)-1)`

change depending on actual start cell

`ROWS` function, used this way, will increment by 1 each row and is more "robust" than alternatives using `ROW` for example

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your formula is in row 2, you could do this:

```
=CONCATENATE("Sheet2!", SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("String to Search For", Sheet2!$13:$13,0),4),1,""),text(row()+15,"#"))
```

If your formulas starts on a different row, just change the 15 as needed.

Comment: Thanks TTG Guy, looks like this may solve the problem!